# How to create concentric graph based on a count stored in each node?

Tags: python, cytoscape.js, cytoscape-web

I have count parameter for each node on the basis of which I want to create concentric graph i.e nearest nodes to the centre have more count than the outer ones.How can I achieve it?

For this I have included following code in my javascript but I don't know how can I use it.

```
concentric: function( node ){
      return node.degree();
    },
    levelWidth: function( nodes ){
      return 2;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

With given: http://js.cytoscape.org/#layouts/concentric, these are properties of layout that you can overwrite. 
For example here: https://github.com/cytoscape/cytoscape.js/blob/9635c63cad2eeb91c873759226f70d9c428ace1d/documentation/demos/performance-tuning/code.js positions will be adjust by the weight property in added node.
So you can try for example this:

```
concentric: function( node ){
  return node.data('count');
}
```

Of course you can modify this function, depends of how value for your count parameter is looking like

```
concentric: function( node ){
  return node.data('count') / 3;
}
```

When I was working with cytoscape I was just pasting whole config to my application and changing them to see what will be best for my graph and data I have in my nodes :)